# Showing document from Google Docs in a WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, google-docs

Problem with showing google docs in WebView (Android)

[image]

this is my code

```
mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+ "https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7pKTkDz8c3gWGNRTWJidTBTVmc/edit?usp=sharing");
```

when i click *here* my android shows options to open the link (like Browser, Chrome, Drive, Internet) and opens the link well in popup Browser!

Comment: So is your problem that it will not display by default?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### How To Force Android WebView to Process Redirects

Google is redirecting you to another URL, and the `WebView` is allowing the OS to process the redirect.

Use this code for the `WebView` to internally process redirects:

```
    // By default, redirects cause jump from WebView to default
    // system browser. Overriding url loading allows the WebView  
    // to load the redirect into this screen.
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Incidentally, you can do lots of other cool stuff in this function, such as custom handling of various URLs.

Comment: Hi david.. Can you please look at this.. Do you have any idea about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975492/remove-sign-in-button-in-google-docs-webview-in-android

Comment: I won't be able to help much Selva, but try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26998896/376829