# How to open doc file in android from url

Tags: android, google-docs, doc

I want to read doc file from url in my android application, i am doing it with google docs like below but i am not getting result.

```
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+urlOfDocument);
```

is there any solution about that? how can i achieve it?

Thank You

Comment: There is no error its just displaying the html and script coding

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981431/showing-document-from-google-docs-in-a-webview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
WebView urlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.containWebView);
urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
urlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
urlWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
urlWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                + "YOUR_DOC_URL_HERE"); 

public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {



    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

EDIT: IF not work, check your URL in device browser to ensure it is working fine

Comment: Thank you for your answer but its not working, is there any other solution?

Comment: Do you try to load the URL in your device browser ??

Comment: Hey thanks dude its working fine, actually the url which i was calling was not working proper, i tried with different url and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, there is result coming. But your WebView's size is 0 and 0.

So you need to reset the LayoutParam by implement the "onPageFinished."