# Open file by URL

Tags: android

I have `FileOpener` class for open documents by URL:

```
public class FileOpener {


    private FileOpener() {
    }

    private static String url;
    private static Uri uri;
    private static Intent intent;

    public static void open(Context context, FileDTO fileDTO) {
        fileDTO.setUrl("https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx");
        setupBase(fileDTO);
        checkFileTypeByUrl();

        try {
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void checkFileTypeByUrl() {

    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
    }

    private static void setupBase(FileDTO fileDTO) {
        url = fileDTO.getUrl();
        uri = Uri.parse(url);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    }
}
```

In activity/fragment it's look like this:

```
    @Override
    public void openOrDownloadFile(FileDTO file) {
        FileOpener.open(getContext(), file);
    }
```

It's work fine for `PDF/Txt` documents, but for `MsWord/MsExcel/MsPowerPoint` have `ActivityNotFoundException` (I have `word/excel/powerpoint` on my device, which opening from other applications without problem)

**Stacktrace:**

> W/System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
>   found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx
>   typ=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
>   flg=0x4000000 }

What could be the problem?

Comment: Firstly You have to download the file ,then only you can proceed to open it .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772663/how-to-open-doc-file-in-android-from-url

Comment: Hi, Could you please share your implementation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see an example of ACTION_VIEW intent filter for the app to open files:

```
<intent-filter android:label="app">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="www.example.com">
</intent-filter>
```

You can see that there is a `android:scheme="https"`, which means that this app will accept `ACTION_VIEW` only with Uris having `https` scheme.
In your case the word app has only `file` scheme, and won't handle `http` or `https` Uris.

So first you have to download the file, and only after that open it as local file.

Answer (score 1):

try this using web view you can load your file from url

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.containWebView);
webview.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
            + "YOUR_DOC_URL_HERE"); 

 public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {



@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

}
}
```